# ASP.NET Web Forms Facebook Open Graph Integration Unable to Add Token to Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I've used this site as a resource to find answers for my questions numerous times, but this is my first time posting; as I am unable to locate an answer that fixes my problem.

I'm trying to build a simple Facebook application that will publish a single static post to any user's stream that adds the application (and can repost the message as many times as they'd like (for points) using a button control).

I've found tons of source code and different approaches to the C# Facebook SDK, but I'm currently getting an error when testing the implementation in its current state that suggests the accessToken is null, thus making any attempt to use it for data collection impossible.

Here's the code I'm attempting (I'm passing through the HttpContext context variable):

```
var accessToken = context.Request["accessToken"];
        var accessToken_copy = context.Request["AccessToken"];
        context.Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;
        if (accessToken_copy == null)
        {
            try
            {
                accessToken_copy = context.Request["accessToken"];
            }
            catch
            {
                accessToken_copy = SampleToken;
            }
        }

        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken_copy);
        dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
        name = result.name;
        receiptID = result.id;
```

Here's the error that the server is throwing:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: accessToken
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: accessToken

Source Error:

Line 44: 
Line 45: 
Line 46:             var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken_copy);
Line 47:             dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
Line 48:             name = result.name;
```

Any assistance would be very helpful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot "/" at end of  "me"

see

```
dynamic result = client.Get("me/", new {fields ="name,id"});
```